# Is it possible to tell the duration of someone else's lure?

Tags: pokemon-go

Quite often when I open Pokemon Go at home I can see a Pokestop with a lure module on at the edge of the map view and multiple times now as I'm on my way towards it the lure ends. Is there any way to tell how long is remaining on the module from afar?

Comment: Don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot tell the duration of the lures.

Comment: If you're brave and feel comfortable/safe doing so, you could try to ask the player if they are present.

Comment: @Ekmod the point is that you know how long is left on the lure before deciding to travel a distance to get to the stop, so that you don't waste your time if it's about to expire.

Comment: @Aequitas, And that's what I get for not reading the question thoroughly. Disregard my dumb comment everybody.

Comment: That's what I thought but I didn't want to be overlooking something little like the amount of petals or some other dumb thing. Hopefully something is added eventually that saves everyone time.

Comment: @Andrew You are telling this based on which evidence? If this is based on anecdotal evidence could you share with us what you've done to arrive at this conclusion.

Comment: @Montag451 I've been around lures plenty of times, and I have seen no differences in the PokeStop screen or map from the moment after they're enabled to the moment before they end.